# elasticsearch error while sorting and paginatioon

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, pagination

I am using the Java API for ElasticSeach and I realized it was not applying correctly the sorting and pagination. My logic is working but because I am currently retrieving all the indexed documents, then applying the ordering logic and then the pagination (but manually). This is an issue because resource consumption will be high as there is a lot of demand.
My question is: There any way to let the API knw I want to order first and then apply pagination logic (this part I have seen how but well its not applied correctly)...

I am trying to use the Java API for elasticsearch to apply correctly the sorting and filtering... I  am expecting to use the API and not applying all by my own.

Comment: Does your query have clauses match, sort and pagination?

Comment: Yes of course... I have all of them...
`code`
For pagination: I use "from" and "size" methods from SearchSourceBuilder.
For clauses: I use a serie of them that end up with a BoolQueryBuilder.
For sorting: I use SortBuilders.
`code`



Thing is that I dont want to load all documents in memory and do all this by my own (it would be working though). I would like the API to sort first and then paginate because if not results are weird... Already sorting is weird...